# abreviar numeros con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de lograr abvreviar los numeros, con el fin de que
1000 sea 1K
1,000,000 sea 1M
1,000,000,000,000 sea 1B
1,000,000,000,000,000,000 sea 1T
etc.

Encontre y quise usar este codigo

```js
Number.prototype["abrv"] = function () {
    let value = this, bN = 0;
    const sf = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T", "C", "Q", "S"];
    while (value > 999) {
        value /= 1000;
        bN++;
    }
    return value.toFixed(2) + sf[bN];
}
```

pero no funciona como es esperado ya que 1 billon lo devuelve como un trillon
plz ayuda

Comment: ¿Y si agregas `KM` para mil millones?

Comment: Correcto Triby, creo que copiaste este codigo de un sitio en ingles.  La definicion de billon es diferente en Estados Unidos que en America Latina

Answer (score 0):

Vale, no se si es necesario extender las funcionalidades de Number, pero te propongo este método

```
const sizes = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T", "C", "Q", "S"];
function reduce(value) {
    const i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(1000)));
    return Math.round(value / Math.pow(1000, i), 2) + " " + sizes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te habian dicho, solo es adicionar el `KM` en las opciones de abreviación, así te irá colocando los miles de millones y luego si el Billón

```js
Number.prototype["abrv"] = function () {
    let value = this, bN = 0;
    const sf = ["", "K", "M", "KM", "B", "T", "C", "Q", "S"];
    while (value > 999) {
        value /= 1000;
        bN++;
    }
    return value.toFixed(2) + sf[bN];
}
```